# how do i print function involving 2 variables x and y in a range from 1 to 10000

Tags: python-3.x

```
def mynewfunction(x,y):
    z=x**3+3*x*y+20*y
    print(z)
for z  in range (1,10000):
    print mynewfunction (x,y)
```

The syntax error I am getting is

```
File "<ipython-input-86-9c167c52d9cb>", line 2
    print mynewfunction (x,y)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

`print` is a function in Python 3, and like any function its argument list must be given in parentheses:

```
print(mynewfunction(x,y))
```